# set content Blank after form is submitted

Tags: reactjs

I have a textarea in my form on which I want to show blank textarea field after form submit. Currently it shows the typed text in textarea even after form submitted. I am getting really confused because the form working is in both component(parent-child).

```
# Parent component
const examples = (props) => {
const [ data, setData ] = useState({});

const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const content = data.content;

axios.post(
 `....................`,
content,
config 
)
.then((res) => setOthers(res.data.others))

return(
 .....
 .....
 < Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler} setData={setData}  />)
```

as for the child component

```
const Form = (props)  => {
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  content: '',
});
const { content } = formData;

const onChange = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const name = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;

setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
props.setData(data => ({ ...data, [name]: value })); 
}

return (
<form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
    <div className="col-12">
        <textarea 
          className="form-control"
          name="content"
          value={content}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          >
          
        </textarea>
    </div>
```

I know I need to set  content: '  ' again after form is submitted but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSubmit=()=>{
 content:''
props.onSubmit()
}

 return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<div className="col-12">
    <textarea 
      className="form-control"
      name="content"
      value={content}
      onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
      >
    </textarea>
  </div>
```

just set the content to null using a function and call the handler to parent function  from there.
Hope this solves

Comment: I didn't get it why  <form onSubmit={ }> is empty shouldn't it be like <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>  and is handleSubmit is a new arrow function

Comment: please check it now i have modified the answer